# Multiple Google Analytics for Multiple pagepath

Tags: google-analytics

I have a landing page with one domain with multiple page path depending on my clients location,

Now, I have already setup different GA tracking code and I want to track this way

GA Property Code 1 = [www.example.com/page/path1](http://www.example.com/page/path1), [www.example.com/page/path2](http://www.example.com/page/path2), [www.example.com/page/path3](http://www.example.com/page/path3) etc

GA Property Code 2 = [www.example.com/page/path10](http://www.example.com/page/path10), [www.example.com/page/path15](http://www.example.com/page/path15), [www.example.com/page/path16](http://www.example.com/page/path16) etc

How do I go about this?

Comment: Your question needs clarifications.. How are those paths created? Child pages? How about assigning those pages to a custom taxonomy, say, Locations and conditionally check using `has_term` to add the tracking code?

Answer (score 0):

You hook into the `wp_footer` and add your GA code.

Here's is how I would do it.

### Option 1:

Get the current URL and counter check it with you selected URLs.

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpse388915_custom_ga_code', 99);
function wpse388915_custom_ga_code() {

    $current_url = (is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
    switch($current_url) {
        case 'www.example.com/page/path1': 
        case 'www.example.com/page/path2': 
        case 'www.example.com/page/path3': 
            echo 'GA Property Code 1';
            break;
        
        case 'www.example.com/page/path10': 
        case 'www.example.com/page/path15': 
        case 'www.example.com/page/path16': 
            echo 'GA Property Code 2';
            break;
    }
}
```

### Option 2:

Get the current URL, then fetch the post ID from the URL using [`url_to_postid`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/) and counter check it with you selected post/page IDs.

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpse388915_custom_ga_code', 99);
function wpse388915_custom_ga_code() {

    $current_url = (is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
    $post_id = url_to_postid($current_url);
    
    // Return if page does not exist.
    if (!$post_id) return;
    
    $preferred_post_type = get_post_field('post_type', $post_id);
    
    if ($preferred_post_type == 'my_post_type') {
        switch($post_id) {
            case 1: 
            case 2: 
            case 3: 
                echo 'GA Property Code 1';
                break;
            
            case 10: 
            case 15: 
            case 16: 
                echo 'GA Property Code 2';
                break;
        }
    }
}
```